# Is there an easy way to view which recipes/plans are already known?

Tags: fallout-76

In Fallout 76, is there any way to tell which plans & recipes have already been learned in the vendor trade screen? Or, is there a way to determine this info on your pip-boy menu?

When a plan or recipe is in your inventory, it's simple enough to tell if you have it or not by trying to learn it. If you already know it, it will not allow you to use it. However, when trading with a vendor, I can't seem to tell if I know the plans/recipes they are offering for sale. It'd be a huge waste of caps to buy a plan or recipe, only to find out after purchase that I already had learned it. Is there any way to know this in the trade menu (or even in the pip-boy menus, so I can view this info at the vendor's location before purchase)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the [January 29th 2019 patch](https://fallout.bethesda.net/en/article/2J2ong0O2B6GAI1AeIdGcp/fallout-76-patch-notes-january-29-2019), plans now indicate if they are known when viewing them in your inventory or in the game world:

> When viewing a plan or recipe in a menu, a “(Known)” tag will now appear next to the names of recipes and plans the player has already learned.

While it's not a list you can view, you will at least be able to know if you need to pick the plan up and read it.

Answer (score 2):

### Unfortunately, no.

At this time, there is no such way. I've looked high and low. I've found no easy way, in fact I've found no way at all to see the already known recipes. I've bought many duplicates as well, it's quite frustrating.

Comment: Ack... I was afraid this was the case. That's unfortunate... it makes me so much more reserved about buying any plans or recipes. I have basically only been buying ones I am *positive* I don't own. Thanks for the quick answer.